# OLED and AMOLED displays

Tags: keyboard, display, laptop, brightness, backlight

I know in the realm of LCD displays it makes sense to control the brightness of the screen by modulating the brightness of the white backlight that illuminates the screen as a whole. However in case of LED displays, each pixel is lit independently and since this is the case, it doesn't make sense to have the `/sys/class/backlight` directory and the files and directories in it. My questions are the following:

1. Do laptops and desktop computers with OLED and AMOLED or any other LED lighting technology have the `/sys/class/backlight` directory and the files and directories in it.
2. And is the increasingly ubiquitous problem of lacking the `/sys/class/backlight` directory in Ubuntu and other related linux distros a result of the systems' having LED based display technologies.
3. Since most linux systems - and third party software like `xrandr` control screen brightness by modulating the value of the `brightness` file in `/sys/class/backlight` directory, what is to be done for the controlling of screen brightness in systems of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to resurrect an ancient thread, but since I'm here and you asked, I can answer (1) anecdotally, as my laptop with an OLED screen on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS does indeed have a /sys/class/backlight folder and screen brightness is indeed changed via xrandr (although that had to be done via a script that polls /sys/class/backlight/actual_brightness, it didn't work out of box).

As far as the display drivers are concerned I don't think there is a semantic difference between LCD backlight and OLED brightness, so it makes sense the mechanism is the same. In both cases you want to change the intensity of the display's illumination. To that extent, what does it matter if it's via a uniform backlight on an LCD or varying perceived pixel intensity on an OLED panel?

I do see what you mean though, in a literal sense it's genuinely *not* a backlight, after all!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, LED and OLED are 2 different things. You seem to refer to LED as OLED, when LED is just a normal display with a backlight and OLED is the special display with no backlight and individually lit pixels. LED displays, like LCD displays, have backlights. [OLED vs LED](https://www.digitaltrends.com/home-theater/oled-vs-led/)

1. I have a ThinkPad X1 Yoga 1st gen OLED and I can confirm I have `/sys/class/backlight` directory and the files and directories in it.
2. I don't lack that directory, in fact, all software and desktop environments I use edit the files in `/sys/class/backlight` as if I were using an LCD laptop, not an OLED one. To the extent of what I've seen, by default, everything behaves normally, but changes in the brightness file do nothing because OLED screens have no backlight.
3. A good answer is "color correction". OLED panels have no backlight, and so, the amount of light they emit is based on the color they emit. To have them emit less light, you can have colors that emit less light. As for an actual implementation of this, [this repository](https://github.com/lawleagle/oled-linux) watches for changes in the brightness file of the OLED panel and applies them to the screen by using "color correction".

I used quotes for "color correction" because there is no perceived effect of colors changing. That is what is happening in the background, but to the human eye, it's just less/more brightness. I can say this from experience, I've been using OLED panels since the first time they came out in 2016 on the ThinkPad x1 Yoga.